# ios - Is it technically possible to set image as iphone background from app?

Tags: ios, image, background, set, photo

I googled for this but couldn't get any useful answer.. so I am asking here :(
My app is supposed to save a image from web and set it as the background of the user's phone.
I know that the user can set image as a background from native Photo app. But I am wondering if this is also possible to do from my own app. If so, what class and function should I use?
If not, will I just let the user save the image from web and manually set it as background by executing the native Photo app?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not do it by programmatically because Apples does not provide this types for feature. You can set image as BackGroung of Device (iPhone) by Apple's Built-in Functionality.
Yes may be it is possible in JB Device.